# Sublime Text 2 Lines too Far Right

Tags: indentation, sublimetext2

I opened my laptop to code in Sublime Text 2 today, and every single file has it's starting indent line in the middle of the screen. I'm not sure what to call it, but, for example, this text box for my question starts my cursor for typing at the far left edge of the box.

This morning, that line is in the middle of the Sublime text editor. Instead of every line starting from the far left, their starting line is in the middle of the text editor window. It sounds small, but it bugs me quite a bit.

What setting is this? How can I get my normal indentation back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screenshot?

Anyway, what does this setting in your `Preferences.sublime-settings` say?

```
// Draws text centered in the window rather than left aligned
"draw_centered": false,
```

Comment: When I restarted Sublime the first time, it did nothing. When I tried it a second time and reopened my project it's completely normal. 

At least now, that preference does say "draw_centered": false, though. I don't know what the problem was, but thank you for answering so quickly!

Answer (score 0):

Find your sublime settings (in OSX it's the Sublime text 2- Preferences - Settings (default)) and find the "margin" value (default should be 4). Probably it's changed some how.